# What would cause an iOS UISegmentedControl to highlight two segments?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl in a Xamarin C# iOS app. On occasion, when a segment is already selected and I select another one, it keeps both highlighted:

[image: Two segments highlighted]

My first thought was that the code being executed on the segment's ValueChanged event was running too much on the UI Thread, which maybe prevented the OS from running the code to switch the highlighting. So, I tried a quick test to see if I could run it in another thread:

```
    private void DefSeg_ValueChanged(object sender, nint selectedSegment)
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
                viewerSettings.SetDefinitionVisibleState(selectedSegment);
                })
        );
    }
```

But this didn't fix it. What would cause the OS to highlight both segments at once?

One other piece of information that may be relevant or not: The UISegmentedControl is being created inside of a UITableViewCell using Monotouch.Dialog.

Comment: Try to test on a real device to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @ColeXia Yes, it does.